# Copy files over network & delete files from same folder windows 7

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to copy my software backup files to another PC in my DC, but copy & xcopy not worked as i desire, let me explain the scenario,

```
db-DIP201901010910.bak
db-DIP201901010920.bak
db-DIP201901010930.bak
db-DIP201901010940.bak
db-DIP201901010950.bak
```

these are the files name, after every 10 minutes a new backup file add but the last 6th one is delete,

so i need a command that copy & delete files as per software backup.

I tried this but it is not working as expected.

```
copy d:\backup\ \\mis-naveed\backup /y /c
```

Comment: What is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: I don't know the exact command for this, i use typical command for copy but not working as i desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways, easiest would probably be:

```
robocopy "d:\backup" "\\mis-naveed\backup" /MOV
```

Where you could even run it in a loop with a timeout:

```
@echo off
:start
robocopy "d:\backup\" "\\mis-naveed\backup" /MOV
timeout /t 600>nul
goto :start
```

another method is a for loop and even log the output:

```
(@for %%i in (D:\backup\*.bak) do (
    copy /Y "%%i" "\\mis-naveed\backup"
    del /Q "%%i"
 )
)>>Somelogfiletxt
```

I strongly suggest you open `cmd.exe` and run the help for more assistance on the above used commands.

```
for /?
copy /?
robocopy /?
del /?
```

etc.

Comment: I am not reading readonly files, your point is invalid. ignoring your messages??seems like I responded.... so how about ignoring my answers completely as of now? I once again request you delete irrelevant comments to my answers.. I will delete this the second you deleted your irrelevant comments.

Comment: If you speak to me in a comment in any answer of yours, please use the @ as notifier, else I will never get notified. On my answers I will get notified, so please do not assume that I am ignoring you.

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot for your kind support

robocopy "d:\backup" "\\mis-naveed\backup" /MOV

its ok but this command not delete extra copies of files from source,

it's my mistake that i'm not clear explain what to do,


robocopy "d:\backup" "\\mis-naveed\backup" /PURGE


robocopy "d:\backup" "\\mis-naveed\backup" /MIR


after your command i'm check option of robocopy, 

so the /PURGE & /MIR is solve my problem

Thanks once again @GerhardBarnard